# Getting this Directory Listing For / when running my web project?

Tags: java

Im a beginner i java, Im doing a java web applicatiom, but when im rying to access my project in browser im getting "Directory Listing For /" statement. why this so?

Comment: elsipse IDE integrated with tomcat 7. Im getting tomcat homepage.

Comment: To clarify, are you using http://localhost:8080/ or http://localhost:8080/your-project-name ? By default Web Tools binds your WAR to the latter. The former would give you the tomcat homepage.

Comment: http://localhost/myProject -> im using this

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have default web page to land to.

Typically such page is called `index.html`. Try to add this page to the root of your project and try again.

Comment: im added index.html inside WEB-INF still im getting same error

Comment: Why do you put it in WEB-INF? Place it at the root, since this is the URL you're trying. WEB-INF is precisely the only directory of the webapp that is not accessible from the outside.

Comment: @JBNizet is your project have servlet

Comment: I have been involved in many projects involving servlets, if that's your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution you need ...

you must know the basics about `Dynamic Web Application`

In Eclipse when you create a new `Dynamic Web Project` and then run the project you will get the directory list

read the reference #1 you will feel happy to read it don`t be afraid i read it

[Apache Tomcat 7
How to Install & Configure](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/tomcat_howto.html)

and #2
[How do I specify the Tomcat context configuration for my Web Application?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_do_I_specify_the_Tomcat_context_configuration_for_my_Web_Application.3F)

they summerize the reference

[Official reference from Tomcat site you may find it advanced ! so keep it as last resort](http://tomcat.apache.org/)

after reading reference #1 you will understand the solution

i created new dynamic web project named **`test`** the

1- "Change Port Of server" go to **`server.xml`** file in your Servers folder and modify

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="9999" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

i did not do any thing but to specify the port to `9999` instead of the `default` one
note: this step is not a must but some times the default port is used by another program , you do it to make sure.

2- "Assign Context Path Parameter" Now go to **`context.xml`** in Servers folder too and put your **context path**

```
<Context reloadable="true" path="/test">
```

All i did in this step is putting path attribute and assign it to test for example but name it as your project name as best practice

3- "Assign relative Url" I created NewFile.jsp in the root of my project
and in **`WEB-INF`** folder the file **`web.xml`**

put these lines and remove the existing default ones

```
<display-name>test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>    
    <welcome-file>NewFile.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

This means the default page when run the project
thats what i read, understood and tested